# \arraystretch in conjunction with booktabs

Tags: tables, booktabs

I'm trying to enlarge the row-height of my `booktabs`-table but `\arraystretch` does this asymmetrically.

I am slightly confused because this is an obvious problem to me and I couldn't find any solutions or workarounds. So please let it pass if I'm just clouded...

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}                                                                                                 
\usepackage{booktabs}
%
\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3} 
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \toprule
    parameter & order of magnitude\\\midrule
    density \hfill$\varrho$ & $0$\\
    velocity \hfill$v$& test\\
    diameter \hfill$d$& test\\
    viscosity \hfill$\mu$ & $0$\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Thanks and cheers,
Stephan

Comment: Simple: don't change `\arraystretch` when using `booktabs`, but insert `\addlinespace` (see the package manual) between rows if you really want to spread lines (you don't, in my opinion).

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, this is a possible but not very applicable workaround. I would have to add it twice in each row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symmetrical way can be obtained with the `cellspace` package: it lets you decide on a minimal vertical spacing between the top of a cell and the bottom of the cell above, and between the bottom of a cell and the top of the cell below. You then have to prefix the specifiers of the columns for which it is useful with the letter `S`. Note that these minimal spacings can be set independently for the top and the bottom of cells. Also, it conflicts with the `S qualifier` from the `siunitx` package, which introduces the letter `C`  as a replacement in its last version (§ 7.11 of the siunitx doc):

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
%
\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular}{SlSr}
    \toprule
    parameter & order of magnitude\\\midrule
    density \hfill$\varrho$ & $0$\\
    velocity \hfill$v$& test\\
    diameter \hfill$d$& test\\
    viscosity \hfill$\mu$ & $0$\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Just two things: (**1**) Why do I have to add the **S** twice since the first already affects the complete table(?) and (**2**) `cellspace` collides with the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)-package, that replaces the **S** with a **C** (compare *7.10* of the [manual](https://www.dpg-physik.de/dpg/gliederung/junge/rg/wuerzburg/Archiv/WS%202011-12/LaTeX/siunitx.pdf)).

Comment: @smoneck: You're right. For 1) I wanted to give as simple an explanation as possible, but I'll correct it. For 2), in the latest version of `siunitx`, a `C` prefix is introduced as a prefix replacement(§ 7.11).

Comment: Uh, yeah... shame on me. I linked an outdated manual-version. It was before my first coffee.